# Pip install location

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.6

I have python2.7 and python3.6 installed side by side in my computer. Now when I install a package using "pip install", how can I know in which python's site-packages is my package going to be installed?

Thank you.

Comment: Execute `where pip` (windows) or `which pip`(linux) to see which pip is going to be used. The first location will tell you the python version.

Comment: it gave me the following output - C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe
C:\Python36\Scripts\pip.exe

Comment: That means, python 2.7 will be used as it is the first one. If you want python 3 instead, just `cd` to the python 3 script directory  and execute pip.

Answer (score 5):

When you have both version 2 and 3 installations `pip` and `pip3` differentiate the target installtion.

For installing anything on Python 3(versions 3.5 and above) use `pip3`

for Python 2.7 use `pip`

Make sure python path is set in environment variables too.

also you can use `where pip` or `which pip` as @mshsayem mentioned.

Additional [Reference](https://www.quora.com/What-is-difference-between-pip-and-pip3)

Comment: So if I use "pip install" it is automatically going to install inside python2.7 and if I use "pip3 install" it will automatically install inside python3.6....am I correct?

Comment: Yes. thats how I install packages on my Ubuntu which has both 2.7 and 3.6

Answer (score 3):

if you use virtualenv, the modules are located in:

```
{path_to_your_virtualenv}/lib/python{your_python_version}/site-packages/
```

and if you don't use virtualenv, normally are installed in:

```
/usr/local/lib/python{your_python_version}
```

You have to use pip3 for install python3 modules.

Answer (score 3):

Check where a specific package is installed by:

```
pip3 show <package_name>
```

List all installed packages with install locations by:

```
pip3 list -v
```

Check the install location used by default when installed without `sudo`:

```
pip3 --version
```

and the location for packages installed with `sudo`, meaning system-wide installation:

```
sudo pip3 --version
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the location of pip by `which pip`. Then you view the pip executable header using `` head `which pip` `` or using your preferred editor. You can find the python interpreter location on the first line. You may have a pip2 and a pip3 executable.

By the way, you can run pip as a python module by `python -m pip <command>`. In this way, you can specify your python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to you question is divided to two parts:
1. Which python version the native terminal selects for me?
2. How do I specify which python version to use?

**Which python version the native terminal selects for me?**

In *windows*, the default pip that will be used is the one associated with the default python version you use. You can edit it in the PATH environmental variable (Start->find-type "Environmental" and click "Edit system variables"). Look the PATH variable and see which version of python is listed. If both versions are listed, windows will select the first.

See more information on system environmental variables [here](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10).

In *Ubuntu/Linux*, usually pip is associated with the native legacy version (2.7), pip3 is associated with Python3.5.x and pip3.6 is associated with Python3.6.x.

However, if you are using Unix OS (such as Ubuntu) or Mac, it is highly recommended to use virtualenv and activate it. See [Official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/venv.html#module-venv) to see how to use it. It's true for both Python2.7 and 
Python3.6. In short, you will create a lightweight copy of you python installation without any packages, and, your installed packages will be installed within this virtual environment. Once you activate a virtual environment, the pip is associated with this environment.

**How do I specify which python version to use?**

You have multiple choices to specify in which environment you want to install the package. It depends if you are on Windows/Linux/MAC.
Shortly, you have the following options:

- Use an IDE and let it help you manage your packages (e.g. Pycharm). Using PyCharm, you will find it very easy to use its package manager. You can also open the IDE's terminal and when you use pip, it will use the package manager of the selected interpreter. See [official documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html).
- Use OS native terminal and specify the version.  In windows, the easiest way is to go to a command line or powershell, and type "c:\path\to\python.exe -m pip install ". On Ubuntu, use pip/pip3/pip3.6. Again, on Ubuntu it is highly recommended to use venv (virtual environment) since installing wrong package on the wrong version can interrupt the native python (Ubuntu uses python for multiple reasons such as the GNOME GUI).
- Use virtual environments. You can look it up, there are plenty of threads explaining on that, as well as the [Official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/venv.html#module-venv).